# Java File Copying - same file to 10/20 USB devices parallely

Tags: java, file, concurrency

I have build a java application which is copying a folder to a `USB pen drive.`
I have done it nicely with,

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, destination);
```

But now I need to make the application to copy that folder to 10-20 USB pen drives in parallel.I know java concurrency a little.but as the file is about `125MB` ,and reading from the same location.i have some doubts.and I need a way to start.Please give me some Ideas.

Thank you EXPERTS.

```
Edit
```

I have completed the Project successfully.I've used the `Runnable` to each `USB device`
And for the issue "reading from the same location" I've used the `RAMDISC`.It is working fine.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you read it from a magnetic hard disk, multiple threads bounce the disk between seeks. So I think you'll get a poorer performance than a 10 * sequential copy.

Comment: Yes that's my point...Can U suggest me another way.

Comment: It is always one location to copy or it is a tree of files ?

Comment: If you read a file instead a folder, you could use `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` to multiple destinations

Comment: Read either the whole directory, or one file at a time into RAM and then write in parallel from RAM to multiple USB pen drives.

Comment: 125mb is practically nothing; the OS will cache it on the first read. The question is how you will connect 10+ usb devices. If its through a HUB don't even think about parallelizeing anything; the HUB will be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<FileOutputStream> outs = new ArrayList<FileOutputStream>();


    //fill the list with destination file for all your USB key
    ...     


    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try
    {
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File("location of source file"));
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) > -1)
            for (final FileOutputStream fos : outs)
                fos.write(buffer, 0, read);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        for (final FileOutputStream fos : outs)
            if (fos != null)
                try
                {
                    fos.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e2)
                {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }

        if (fis != null)
            try
            {
                fis.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e2)
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

The plus side is that this code will not make your HD go crazy on seek. On the other hand, you are not taking advantage of multi core architecture.